# how to setup orcale wallet in flyway.conf

Tags: oracle, jdbc, configuration, flyway, wallet

can someone help to setup correct jdbc connection string using oracle wallet in flyway conf?

If I tried sqlplus /@WALLET_NAME it works perfect, but by flyway it always wants credentials (no error).

I have flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:/@WALLET_NAME also tried flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@WALLET_NAME

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the free flyway version. And it seems that's a paid feature.
See here and check the flyway teams label:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/oracleWalletLocation

I tried to use Flyway. But, the free version doesn't support Oracle Wallet.  And this is mandatory to use Oracle Autonomous Database on Oracle Cloud.

And the paid version is too expensive for me.
So, I decided to go back to Liquibase.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30223420)